# Eloquent save works but object is empty

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating a new record. The record saves successfully, but the object is empty, including the id.

In my controller, I have:

```
$shop = new Shop();

$shop->create($this->data['Shop']) //array of Shop data, such as "name"

echo $shop->id //this returns NULL, but new record has been saved
```

My model looks like this:

```
class Shop extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

  protected $guarded = ['id'];

}
```

I am wanting at least the new "id", but ideally the $shop object would have all the attribute data loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
$shop = Shop::create($this->data['Shop']);

echo $shop->id;
```

[Reference](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

Comment: I've updated my question. I am dumping the contents of $shop and the id (and attributes) are NULL.

Comment: @mattcrowe No, you use it wrong way. Look at my code and compare it with yours. It's not the same

Comment: Ah sorry. Totally overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$shop = new Shop();
$shop->name = 'Shop';
$shop->save();
echo $shop->id;
```

id isn’t available until you save